# iFrame with Fixed Header

Tags: iframe, css-position

I would like to do something similar to this:
http://bit.ly/RLpHme

I'm working on a website for a real estate agent, and she would like to load the listings from her partners site, but have a fixed header at the top with her information.

How would I go about achieving this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

fixed header with iFrame, check http://jsfiddle.net/QQKc4/50/

```
<div id="headerfix"></div>
<iframe id="preview-frame" src="http://www.test.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

CSS

```
#headerfix {
    height: 60px;
    background-color:#DDD;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #59A3C8;
    z-index: 99999;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
#preview-frame {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 60px;
    width:100%;
    height: 581px;
}
```

Comment: That is close, but it ends up with a weird double scroll bar.

Comment: because i will give body `height:1000px` remove this.