# How is the iFrame with Header Preview Achieved?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I know this is a general question, but I can't get a true answer on Stackoverflow or searching google. How do I make a page with a fixed header for logo and links and an iFrame of a given URL. The closest I've come across is this [iFrame with Fixed Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550450/iframe-with-fixed-header). What I really want to achieve is [this example on CodeCanyon](http://codecanyon.net/item/livicons-303-truly-animated-vector-icons/full_screen_preview/4618985). The first link gives a decent answer, but the page has two scroll bars. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I want to make the iFrame stretch to the height of the page :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples you linked are using jquery to dynamically adjust the height.

```
//function to adjust height of iframe
var calcHeight = function () {
    var headerDimensions = $('#header-bar').outerHeight(true);
    $('#preview-frame').height($(window).height() - headerDimensions);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    calcHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    calcHeight();
}).load(function () {
    calcHeight();
});
```

This is the code i used to dynamically adjust the height.

you can see it here in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QQKc4/11/

Answer (score 1):

You would have your HTML something like this...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:[[some value you want in px]]"; width:100%;>
The logo and links come here
</div>
<iframe src="[[the url to load]]" style="width:100%;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Note - The inline styles can be moved to a stylesheet, and for the iframe, you'll need to calculate the window height minus the header div height with javascript/jQuery and apply the height to the iframe

Comment: I'm using something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/ebv8j/

I want the iframe to fit the height of the page.

Comment: @EfrainAnthonyNegron i added the jquery snippet to your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ebv8j/3/

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height:(x)px; width:100%; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; z-index:2;">
            The logo and links come here
        </div>
        <div style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; z-index:1">
            <iframe src="xx.html" style="margin-top:(x)px; width:inherit; height:inherit"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```